# Convert QString Unix epoch time to QString standard time

Tags: qt, datetime, epoch, qstring

I need an elegant C++ function that takes a QString parameter containing the unix time (e.g. 1295874681) and converts it into standard time format (e.g Mon, 24 Jan 2011 13:11:21 GMT) containing QString and returns it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
bool ok;
const uint s = unixTimeStr.toUInt( &ok );
if ( !ok ) {
   ..handle conversion error (unixTimeStr not containing a number)
}
const QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromTime_t( s );
const QString textdate = dt.toString( Qt::TextDate );
```

Comment: so simple the Qt way - instead of stdlib